# Showing error File not foundError: tcl data directory not found on mac osx after creating build using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Using command

```
pyinstaller index.py
```

***Show successfully build create.
when i click my project index it show***

[image: error]

> Note: python version 3.7 
>  pyinstaller version 3.4